# ¿Cómo funciona una asociación manytomany con un formulario que contiene un CollectionType y un EntityType en Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Tengo las siguientes dos entidades:

**Vuelo.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* Vuelo
*
* @ORM\Table(name="vuelos")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VueloRepository")
*/
class Vuelo {

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Pasajero",  cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="vuelos_pasajeros")
 */
private $pasajeros;

public function __construct() {
    $this->pasajeros = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

function getPasajeros() {
    return $this->pasajeros;
}

function setPasajeros($pasajeros) {
    $this->pasajeros = $pasajeros;
}

public function addPasajero(Pasajero $pasajero) {
    $this->pasajeros->add($pasajero);
}

public function removePasajero(Pasajero $pasajero) {
    $this->pasajeros->removeElement($pasajero);
}
```

**Pasajero.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* Pasajero
*
* @ORM\Table(name="pasajeros")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PasajeroRepository")
*/
class Pasajero {

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $nombre;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $apellido;

public function __toString() {
    return $this->nombre . ' ' . $this->apellido;
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

function getNombre() {
    return $this->nombre;
}

function getApellido() {
    return $this->apellido;
}

function setNombre($nombre) {
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
}

function setApellido($apellido) {
    $this->apellido = $apellido;
}

function getPasajero() {
    return $this->pasajero;
}

function setPasajero($pasajero) {
    $this->id = $pasajero->getId();
    $this->nombre = $pasajero->getNombre();
    $this->apellido = $pasajero->getApellido();
}
}
```

Creo el siguiente formulario:

**VueloType.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Vuelo;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

class VueloType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
            ->add('pasajeros', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => PasajeroType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-primary')
            ))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Vuelo::class,
    ));
}

}
```

y el sub formulario:

**PasajeroType.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Pasajero;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PasajeroType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
            ->add('pasajero', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Pasajero',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Pasajero',
                'choice_label' => function ($pasajero) {
                    return $pasajero->getNombre() . " " . $pasajero->getApellido() . " " . $pasajero->getId();
                },
                'choice_value' => 'id', 
                'placeholder' => 'Selecciona',
            ))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Pasajero::class,
    ));
}

}
```

El comportamiento de Symfony en este caso es que se muestra un dropdown con todos los pasajeros disponibles en la tabla "pasajeros". Al seleccionar un pasajero, se graba un registro en la tabla "vuelos_pasajeros", que relaciona ambas tablas. Hasta este punto todo normal pero luego se dan los siguientes dos problenas:

- Al momento de grabar los datos, cada vez, se crea un nuevo registro en la tabla "pasajeros" en vez de simplemente actualizar el registro.
- Al editar la entidad, en el formulario, no aparece seleccionado el pasajero que había editado en el paso anterior.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Es esto un comportamiento esperado?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solucioné el problema de la siguiente manera:

Eliminé por completo el archivo PasajeroType.php y modifique el campo "pasajeros" de VueloType.php así:

```
->add('pasajeros', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Pasajero',
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Pasajero',
                    'choice_label' => function ($pasajero) {
                        return $pasajero->getNombre() . " " . $pasajero->getApellido();
                    },
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'placeholder' => 'Selecciona',
                ),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ))
```